# Сделать на сайте картинку в миллиметрах

Tags: php

есть сайт по обоям,мне нужно сделать так ,чтоб картинка была не в пикселях,а в миллиметрах ,подскажите как это сделать?чтоб человек мог сам выбирать размер какой будет у картинки и на картинке отображалось в см или миллиметрах,а не в пикселях,при его загрузке этой картинки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

96***px*** – это приблизительно 1 ***дюйм***, а 1 ***дюйм*** – это 25.4***мм***

Вот и считаем с помощью элементарного js, что картинка с размерами 1280х720, это приблизительно 339х190***мм***

Comment: просто ширина и высота -это переменные у меня для картинки,подскажите,пожалуйста ,как в таком случае быть?

Comment: // Получаете ваши значения писелях
$height=1, $width = 2;
// 1px = 0.026458333 cm =>
$coeff = 0.026458333;

// Сконвертированные данные
$smH = $height * $coeff;
$smW = $width * $coeff;

Comment: спасибо, последний вопрос, я использую плагин jcron , и там в библиотеке js идут значения в пикселял, мне в этой библиотеке нужно вставлять этот код или можно на сайте?

Comment: Можно на сайте. Просто ловите значения и конвертируйте размеры.

Comment: > 96px – это приблизительно 1 дюйм

очень спорное утверждение.

Comment: @eicto Наверное Вы правы. Вот очень хороший пример подсчета пикселей на дюйм: (самое начало статьи) http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/38-urok-7-layout-parametry-dlja-view-elementov.html

Comment: у меня нет андроида под рукой, но то что я нагуглил по этому поводу говорит что если я сделаю width: 1cm то оно не будет на самом деле 1cm, это правда ?

Comment: Понятия не имею, но думаю такое отклонения не только на android. Как мне это проверить?) У меня не установлен сейчас SDK для android.

Comment: просто - http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2vL8Y/embedded/result/ вот тут черный прямоугольник  должен быть один см шириной (линейкой можно померить)

Comment: У меня получилось по 0,5см. В родном браузере, со стандартными настройками. А у Вас получается 1см. ? И какая ОС?

Comment: Для тех, кто уверен, что можно размеры угадать, предлагаю помедитировать на тему проекторов и googleTV. В случае проектора нет гарантий, что там квадрат. Также, если подключен телевизор (там к примеру может быть принудительно растягиватся изображение).

Comment: наверно я вас ввёл в заблуждение...прошу прощения
мне просто нужен такой ф-ционал как тут
http://fbrush.ru/fotooboi/23-detskie/detail/557-0132

Я понимаю, но вот как это реализовать, уже 3 день сижу думаю...

Comment: в этой задаче не объязательно соблюдать размеры. Там размеры - это проблема печатающих.